# Which processes were running yesterday?

Tags: linux, crash, process, ps

We have a production machine that keeps crashing on regular basis. Our staging environments run fine, but when the application is deployed to production, the production machine crashes after two or three days.

We are unable to find any scenario on staging environment which causes the machine to crash. Is there any way to determine which processes were running when the machine crashed?

This might give an indication to issue with application or machine?

Comment: do you have a linux install made from scratch or are you using a specific distro?

Comment: What is the nature of the application; Web? DB? 
Have you checked the respective logs under /var/log

Comment: as @SteveN said, check the common locations for logs for any occurencies that may match your needs. (/var/log , /var/log/messages ) - for logging you have `syslogd` and `klogd` packages as the most used.

Comment: I've had gone through similar issue in the past, the way I've solved it, was by running a cronjob which executed periodically commands that would have their output persisted to a logfile, like the output of `dmesg -c`, `ps aux`, `cat /proc/net/sockstat`, among others. Then, everyday I'd compare outputs to look for clues on where to start troubleshooting. That maybe one starting point.

Comment: Restart the new application every 24 hours and check if this significantly increases the time-to-crash for production machine.

Comment: Ours is a JEE web application running under tomcat. I seem to like the idea by @Marcel to periodically log the processes.